# Layer image and real time updating heatmap

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I have:

- An image of an insole with 16 pressure sensors.
- A 2*8 numpy array of pressure values for each sensor
- Pressure values update in real time every 0.1[s]

[image: Example image]

I want to:

- Display the image in the background of plot
- Overlay to each pressure sensor(black dot) the Heatmap value of pressure applied
- update pressure values every 0.1[s]

The code below does overlay the updating heatmap with background image, however I don't know how to reposition the heatmap to overlay with the sensors (black dots)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
 #Trial combining heatmap + backgoround image
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((300,400))) # Usually 2*8 but cannot see it 
img = plt.imread(r"..\Desktop\Example_image.PNG")

ax.imshow(img, alpha=0.5)
plt.show(block=False)

# draw some data in loop
for i in range(100):
    # wait for a second
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # PRESSURE SENSOR VALUES USUALLY 2*8, USING 300*400 SO THEY ARE VISIBLE
    Pressue_values = np.random.random((300,400))
    im.set_array(Pressue_values)
    # redraw the figure
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

**How to map the 2*8 pressure values to the correct pressure sensor pixel?**

Current result example - pixels are too small, need to map to correct position and expand to adjacent [image: not correct overlay position]

Comment: `plt.scatter()` will probably work better, if the pressure sensors are spaced irregularly around the sole as shown in the picture.

Comment: why do you say so? cause i can make the scatter poitns larger?

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I misread the question a bit. Each pressure sensor gives an array of 2x8 values (across its surface, I guess?), and you want small heatmaps of those values at the corresponding area in the image? Which way is the data oriented (wider or taller)?

Comment: 16 pressure sensors map to a 16 points (which i store in a 2*8) array. so 1 colour for each pressure sensor. I want the pressure sensor to light up of its corresponding color. so "given 16 values, corresponding to pressure on 16 pressure sensors, how to map plot these values overlaid on the image of the pressure sensors, with color corresponding to 'pressing' (high value)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses a scatter plot to draw circles over the pressure sensors and update the colors based on the input data. You should update `SENSOR_MIN` and `SENSOR_MAX` to match your sensors (this prevents the color scale from changing when the inputs change).

```python
import sys
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# min and max values that the sensors will produce
SENSOR_MIN = 0
SENSOR_MAX = 1

def make_plot(background, coordinates, pressure_data):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.imshow(background)

    coordinates = np.asarray(coordinates).reshape(-1, 2).T
    sc = ax.scatter(
        *coordinates,
        s=10.0**2,
        c=pressure_data.reshape(-1),
        cmap="viridis",
        vmin=SENSOR_MIN,
        vmax=SENSOR_MAX,
    )
    fig.colorbar(sc, label="pressure (some units)")
    return fig, sc

def update_plot(fig, sc, pressure_data):
    """Update the plot with new data and redraw the figure."""
    sc.set_array(pressure_data.reshape(-1))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

def get_data():
    return np.random.random((2, 8))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    background_img = plt.imread("Example_image.PNG")
    # pixel coordinates of each sensor in the background image
    coords = [[[462, 106],
               [547, 113],
               [430, 156],
               [601, 237],
               [543, 222],
               [497, 221],
               [430, 216],
               [444, 266]],
              [[489, 439],
               [609, 463],
               [613, 564],
               [500, 574],
               [568, 641],
               [524, 643],
               [577, 688],
               [527, 683]]]

    fig, sc = make_plot(background_img, coords, get_data())
    # exit the script when the figure is closed
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("close_event", lambda event: sys.exit())
    plt.show(block=False)

    # draw some data in loop
    while True:
        frame_start = time.perf_counter()
        pressure_values = get_data()
        # update the figure
        update_plot(fig, sc, pressure_values)
        # wait for 0.1s (including the time it took to update the plot)
        frame_time = time.perf_counter() - frame_start
        if frame_time < 0.1:
            plt.pause(0.1 - frame_time)
```